# C++ OpenCV Failed to open webcam on another laptop but able to open on desktop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, webcam

My program uses OpenCV library to capture a single image from the webcam and then save it onto the local file system.

Currently it is working fine on my desktop; where my program was developed. But when I test it on my laptop (different device),  it is unable to detect the webcam.

I went ahead to test it on another laptop, but still the same issue occurs.
Both of the laptop's webcam was not in use when I executed my program, and both laptop has only 1 integrated webcam.

> Here are the specifications of the devices and the CMake options for OpenCV.
>
> - **Desktop**
>
>   1. Windows 10 64-bit
>   2. External Webcam connected via USB
>   3. Webcam exist in Device Manager
>   4. Webcam exist in Devices and Printers
> - **Laptop 1**
>
>   1. Windows 10 64-bit
>   2. On-board Webcam (Integrated)
>   3. Webcam exist in Device Manager
>   4. Webcam exist in Devices and Printers
>   5. Able to access webcam on laptop's "Camera" app
> - **Laptop 2**
>
>   1. Windows 10 64-bit
>   2. On-board Webcam (Integrated)
>   3. Webcam exist in Device Manager
>   4. Webcam does not exist in Devices and Printers
>   5. Able to access webcam on laptop's "Camera" app
> - **OpenCV CMake**
>
>   1. v3.30
>   2. BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF (Static Libs)
>   3. WITH_MSMF ON (Media Foundation Support)
>   4. WITH_DSHOW OFF (Tried ON, didn't work, read that it was obsolete)
>   5. BUILD_opencv_world ON

Shown below are my codes:

**Program Headers**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void GetDevID();
void OpenDevice(int);

cv::Mat frame;
```

**main**

```
int main()
{
    // Initially I tried cv::VideoCapture cap.open(0) for default webcam.
    // Unfortunately it only works on my desktop, so I tried opening
    // from -1 to 254, hence GetDevID(). Still does not work.
    GetDevID();
}
```

**GetDevID - Gets the first device that is opened**

```
void GetDevID()
{
    int MaxTested = 254;
    int DevID = -2;
    for (int i = -1; i < MaxTested; i++)
    {
        cv::VideoCapture TestDev(i);
        bool IsDevOpen = TestDev.isOpened();
        TestDev.release();
        if (IsDevOpen)
        {
            DevID = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    OpenDevice(DevID);
}
```

**OpenDevice - Opens tested device**

```
void OpenDevice(int DevID)
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(DevID);
    if (!cap.isOpen())
    {
        // This is where it fails when the program is executed on the laptop
        // Which means the ID from -1 to 254 is not valid
    }
    else
    {
        // Capture 20th frame, for best clarity
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            cap.read(frame);
        }
        cap.release();

        if (frame.empty())
        {
            // Error handling occurs here
        }
        else
        {
            // Continues to save file
        }
    }
}
```

I am all out of luck on Google, and it seems like OpenCV related issues are quite unique.

So if anyone is able to advice me, would be very much appreciated.

Do let me know if I missed out anything on the question as well.

**Edit**

It seems that I might have missed out on a few things, as mentioned by DaveS.

The program ran fine on the desktop and laptops, just that whilst it was running on the laptops, it didn't detect any webcam devices, nor did it throw any error codes.

To the program, it was just as if there are no webcam devices connected, but physically, there is.

I have also tested by connecting the external webcam on the laptop, and the program is still unable to find any webcam devices.

Comment: What happens if you connect the USB webcam to the laptops?
You also don't tell us what the error codes are.  Try adding logging or message boxes if you don't want to use remote debugging.

Comment: Hi @DaveS, thanks for the reply. There was no error codes returned, the program just didn't detect the webcam. Meaning to say, the behavior of the program is running correctly and it just wasn't able to detect the webcam. I have also tested via connecting the USB webcam to the laptops. Still can't detect any webcam.

Comment: Hi, I think that you must research original code of cap_msmf.cpp - in code you will find some debug print out "DebugPrintOut" - especially in `HRESULT ImageGrabber::startGrabbing(void)` method. - it has `        if ((met == MEError) || (met == MENonFatalError))
        {
            pEvent->GetStatus(&hrStatus);
            DebugPrintOut(L"IMAGEGRABBER VIDEODEVICE %i: MEError | MENonFatalError: %u\n", ig_DeviceID, hrStatus);
            break;
        }` - so you should check what it is print out to debug output - do you know how get `DebugPrintOut` debug output?

Comment: P.S. - if you are interested only take photo from web cam - you can try my project https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK#twentyfourthdemoprogram

Comment: Hi @EvgenyPereguda , I have just take a look at your project. Is there any way I can contact you? I'll need some advice on how to integrate your project.

Comment: You can write private message on CodeProject site. If you need chat - so, you can send in private message reference on your gmail for chatting. Or, you can write message to me on site - http://capturemanager.binpress.com